# Heroku only: ancestry gem crashes with undefined method `ancestry' for #<Model:0x#######>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ancestry

I'm seeing an issue on Heroku only with the ancestry gem (cannot reproduce locally):
https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry

A NoMethodError occurred in home#upload:
 undefined method `ancestry' for #

Method looks like this:

```
def anthem_upload
    user = User.find_by(id: params[:user_id])
    anthem = Anthem.create!(user_id: user.id, body:params[:post]) <-- HAPPENS HERE
   ...
ene
```

This method doesn't even call on .ancestry method - but the exception happens as soon as model is created.

Model looks like this:

```
class Anthem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_ancestry
 ...
end
```

Here is the logs:

> ```
> A NoMethodError occurred in home#anthem_upload:
>
>   undefined method `ancestry' for #<Anthem:0x007f1684d58b98>
>   app/controllers/home_controller.rb:335:in `anthem_upload'
> ```

Comment: Can you show the full error trace in the heroku log?

Comment: show your `model_upload` method as well or thats the `anthem_upload` itself?

Comment: model_upload is anthem_upload - same thing it's above. The weird thing is this all works well locally, only on Heroku it explodes

Comment: yeah, the error message is not really saying anything. if you do a project wide search for `ancestry`, what do you get? where is it this method being called in your project?

Comment: Inside, the model there's something you have to add for this gem called "has_ancestry" - and I believe the gem provides that method "ancestry" - except I suspect it's clashing with something on Heroku so it doesn't want to work in that environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must run the migration to add the method `ancestry` to your model:

```
 heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Of course assuming your app works at development. If not you can generate the migration with

```
rails g migration add_ancestry_to_[table] ancestry:string
```

Taken from [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry)

**Edited**

After read your comments, I did try my hypothesis. Adding the `ancestry` gem to a project that doesn't need, and them adding `has_ancestry` to the model `Task`, without migrations, at the console I got:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.2)
~/ (development) > Task.new
=> #<Task:0x00000008a3d088> {
               :id => nil,
       :project_id => nil,
             :name => nil,
      :description => nil,
    :points_budget => nil,
       :created_at => nil,
       :updated_at => nil
}
~/ (development) > Task.new.save
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
NoMethodError: undefined method `ancestry' for #<Task:0x00000008a9c998>
from /home/alejandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails4/gems/activemodel-4.2.2/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
~/ (development) > Task.new.validate
NoMethodError: undefined method `ancestry' for #<Task:0x00000008ad1210>
from /home/alejandro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails4/gems/activemodel-4.2.2/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
```

The same error you got. Of course, I'm at development. You must try something like this at heroku with: `heroku run rails console`

Comment: Thanks but I have done that migration and on heroku as well

Comment: Did you try `heroku restart`. Also you can try, at console: `Anthem.first.ancestry` (if you have stored any record).

Comment: You can run `heroku run rake db:migrate:status` and check if all the migrations are done ok.

Comment: A good hint to debugging here is that it's not finding the column name, then falling back to look for the method name (which is also undefined). Good answer.